# How can I use groupingBy to return a List<String, String>

Tags: java

I have a List of `GroupUser`instances with `String getGroup()` and `String getName()` methods.
I want to return a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the key is the group and the value is the list of names for that group.

If I use

```
Map<String, List<GroupUser>> groupUserList = users.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GroupUser::getGroup));
```

that returns `Map<String, List<GroupUser>>`

How can I get a `Map<String, List<String>>` directly

Comment: What is supposed to represent the String value in a map?

Comment: You say you want the value to be a **list** of names for that group. Why do you then say you want to have `Map<String, String>` and not something like `Map<String, List<String>>`? Typo?

Comment: Think you mean a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the key is the group and the value is a list of names with:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> groupUserList = users.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(GroupUser::getGroup, 
                            Collectors.mapping(GroupUser::getName, 
                                    Collectors.toList())));
```

## Edit

Explaination:

Looking at [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) javadocs we see that 1 of the overloads has the signature:

`public static <T,K,A,D> Collector<T,?,Map<K,D>> groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier,  Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream)`

You can think of this `downstream` as a collector that tells the stream what to do with the elements that it separated by key (in our case the group is the key).

Notice that it **is another collector**. Next we want to transform a `GroupUser` into a `String` which is it's name. We know we transform elements of a stream with `map`. However this takes a `Collector`.

Look further into the [Collectors API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) we see that we already have a collector that maps elements and takes another `Collector`

`public static <T,U,A,R> Collector<T,?,R> mapping(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper, Collector<? super U,A,R> downstream)`

Now from the docs: `downstream - a collector which will accept mapped values`. Since we mapped `GroupedUser` to it's name the last thing left to do is to **collect** them in a list and that is one of the most commonly used collectors. `Collectors.toList()`

Bottom line: Simple usage of collectors tells you that this is where you finished the processing of your stream, however we can *compose collectors* in more complex scenarios like this one.

Comment: Can you also explain how the code works? I think that could be helpful to learn how to make some easy modifications.